# Send push notification via firebase to APNS for safari

Tags: firebase, safari, apple-push-notifications

Currently, my project's using firebase cloud messaging to push notification to Android and IOS app. And we want to use it for web push notification also. Unfortunately, firebase doesn't support Safari. I found that we need to send the notification to APNS for Safari. Since firebase support send the notification to IOS via APNS, can it work with safari?

Comment: I'm reading over the [documentation for Safari Push Notifications (SPN)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/PushNotifications/PushNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013225-CH3-SW1) and it looks like you need to generate a separate signed certificate for pushing web.  This certificate will include your `webServiceURL` to receive deviceToken events.

Comment: Now, you can create this endpoint using Cloud Functions.  The trick is that when you call `window.safari.pushNotification.requestPermission` you are allowed to append `userdata` which could be your firebase user ID, (or device token).  Use this to pair the device token with a user in your Firestore or Realtime Database.  You will probably also need to store the token in a reverse lookup table so you can remove the device when the user opts-out.

Comment: @James Poag we are facing the same issue. We have implemented the FCM and its working on Windows, Mac and Android but not on IOS. I read we can't receive Push Notification on IOS because they are not allowing this. If you have implemented this solution using Angular, it would be great if you send me sample application in which we can send FCM messages on IOS all browsers.